# issue limiting my sql query with pagination class

Tags: php, pagination

```
<?php
/****************************************************************************
* paging.class.php v 1.0
*
* version 1.0
*
* This script allow to generate dynamically navigation of pages on your web site
* It is easy to configure and use this paging class
*
* ----------------------------------------------------------------
*
* You can find examples in the index.php script (with this package)
*

Copyright (C) 2010 Deyan Spasov <deyan@e7studio.com>

*******************************************************************************/

class paging {

    public $showPagesNumber = true;     //Show page number     Example: Page 1 of 20
    public $showPagesForm = true;           //If you want to use pages form. The system show form with input field and go button
    public $showFirstAndLast = true;    //If you have paging buttons first page and last page
    public $showPrevAndNext = true;     //If you have paging button previous page and next page
    public $numberOfPages = 7;              //Set the number of shown pages

    public $pagingClass = 'paging';             //Set css class of your paging
    public $pagingFirstText = '&laquo;';    //Set text of first button
    public $pagingLastText = '&raquo;';     //Set text of last button
    public $pagingPrevText = '&lsaquo;';    //Set text of previous button
    public $pagingNextText = '&rsaquo;';    //Set text of next button
    public $pagingPageText = 'Page';            //Set page text
    public $pagingPageOfText = 'of';            //Set of text
    public $pagingFormButtonText = 'Go';    //Set text of form button


    /*
        Generate standart navigation
        example: generate('?page=', '&category=1', 5, 10, 100)      
        result:  « ‹ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 › »

        @access public

        @parameters
            $frontUrl - Set the url before page number
            $backUrl  - Set the url after page number
            $currentPage - Set the current page number
            $rowsPerPage - Set how many rows you show on page
            $allRows  - Set the number of all rows that you have

        @return string with paging HTML source code
    */
    public function generate($frontUrl, $backUrl, $currentPage, $rowsPerPage, $allRows) {

        if($allRows <= $rowsPerPage) {
            return '';
        }

        $pages = ceil ( $allRows / $rowsPerPage );

        settype($currentPage, "int");

        if($currentPage < 1 || $currentPage > $pages) {
            $currentPage = 1;
        }

        $paging = '<div class="'.$this->pagingClass.'">';

        if ($currentPage > 2 && $this->showFirstAndLast) {
            $paging .= '<a href="' . $frontUrl . '1' . $backUrl . '" title="First page" class="arrows">'.$this->pagingFirstText.'</a>';
        }

        if ($currentPage > 1 && $this->showPrevAndNext) {
            $paging .= '<a href="' . $frontUrl . '' . ($currentPage - 1) . '' . $backUrl . '" title="Previous page" class="arrows">'.$this->pagingPrevText.'</a>';
        }

        $halfPages = $this->numberOfPages / 2;
        settype($halfPages, 'int');

        if($pages > $this->numberOfPages) {
            if($currentPage == 1) {
                for($i = 1; $i <= $this->numberOfPages; $i ++)
                    $paging .= '<a href="' . $frontUrl . '' . $i . '' . $backUrl . '" ' . (($i == $currentPage) ? ' class="selected"' : ' class="normal"') . '>' . $i . '</a>';
            } elseif ($currentPage == $pages) {
                for($i = $pages - $this->numberOfPages + 1; $i <= $pages; $i ++)
                    $paging .= '<a href="' . $frontUrl . '' . $i . '' . $backUrl . '" ' . (($i == $currentPage) ? ' class="selected"' : ' class="normal"') . '>' . $i . '</a>';
            } else {
                $start = $currentPage - $halfPages;

                if($start == 0) {
                    $start = 1;
                }

                if($start < 1) {
                    $start_at = 1;
                    $end = (- 1) * $start + $halfPages + $currentPage;
                } else {
                    $start_at = $start;
                    $end = $start_at + $this->numberOfPages - 1;
                    if ($end > $pages) {
                        $start_at = $start_at - ($end - $pages);
                        $end = $pages;
                    }
                }

                for($i = $start_at; $i <= $end; $i ++)
                    $paging .= '<a href="' . $frontUrl . '' . $i . '' . $backUrl . '" ' . (($i == $currentPage) ? ' class="selected"' : ' class="normal"') . '>' . $i . '</a>';
            }
        } else {
            for($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i ++)
                $paging .= '<a href="' . $frontUrl . '' . $i . '' . $backUrl . '" ' . (($i == $currentPage) ? ' class="selected"' : ' class="normal"') . '>' . $i . '</a>';
        }

        if($currentPage < $pages && $this->showPrevAndNext) {
            $paging .= '<a href="' . $frontUrl . '' . ($currentPage + 1) . '' . $backUrl . '"  title="Next page" class="arrows">'.$this->pagingNextText.'</a>';
        }

        if($currentPage + 1 < $pages && $this->showFirstAndLast) {
            $paging .= '<a href="' . $frontUrl . '' . $pages . '' . $backUrl . '" title="Last page" class="arrows">'.$this->pagingLastText.'</a>';
        }

        if($this->showPagesForm) {
            $paging .= '<form method="post" action="" class="page_form">'.$this->pagingPageText.' <input type="text" name="page" value="" /> <button type="submit" name="go_page">'.$this->pagingFormButtonText.'</button></form>';
        }

        if($this->showPagesNumber) {
            $paging .= '<div class="page_numbers">'.$this->pagingPageText.' '.$currentPage.' '.$this->pagingPageOfText.' '.$pages.'</div>';
        }

        $paging .= '<div style="clear: both"></div>';

        return $paging . "</div>";
    }

}

?>
```

I have this php pagination class and I cannot figure out a way to limit my SQL query. This generates the buttons for pagination just fine, but have no idea how to limit my query output. Also, how would I go about using this class with other variables in my url. because this one doesnt support it I dont think. like.

mypage.php?status=pending&page=4

here is what is in my "working" page.

```
<?php 

require_once('classes/class.paging.php');

// PAGINATION STUFF
$ordercount1 = mysql_query("SELECT * from orders WHERE technumber='$myuserid'");
$ordercount2 = mysql_num_rows($ordercount1);

// echo $ordercount2;

    $pagingClass = new paging();

    $limit = 10;        //Number of rows that we show on page
    $allRows = $ordercount2;    //Number of all rows that we have

    if(isset($_POST['page'])) {
        $_GET['page'] = $_POST['page'];
    }

    if(!isset($_GET['page']) || !is_numeric($_GET['page'])) {
        $_GET['page'] = 1;
    }

    //We off the page number
    $pagingClass->showPagesNumber = false;
    $pagingClass->showPagesForm = false;
    $pagingClass->numberOfPages = 10;
    echo $pagingClass->generate('?page=', '', $_GET['page'], $limit, $allRows);

// END PAGINATION STUFF

?>
```

Comment: limit your query ? what do you mean by that ? and what's the problem with the url variables ? and most important DO NOT use `mysql_*` - not only it is [*deprecated*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) but also it invites sql_injection.

Comment: Limit my queries so I can only show the amount of records, and make it move accordingly on each pagination page.

    $getmyorders = mysql_query("SELECT `orderid`, `status`, `date` FROM orders WHERE technumber ='$myuserid' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT $LIMITER_HERE");

Comment: The $LIMITER_HERE is what I need, as the coder of this class failed to implement this I presume. :(

Comment: For example:
In this script http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-paginate-data-with-php
the limiter for the SQL query is $pages->limit

Comment: any by URL variables say I go to mypage.php?status=pending but with this pagination class if i click for instance page 4 it goes to mypage.php?page=4 instead of mypage.php?status=pending&page=4

Comment: I think it might be something like this but not sure how to write it properly.

$sql_limiter =  " . (($current_page -1) * $limit) . ", " $limit;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The link you provided show the usage:

  $pages = new Paginator;
  $pages->items_total = $num_rows[0];
  $pages->mid_range = 9;
  $pages->paginate();
  echo $pages->display_pages();

In this example `9` is the total number of results from your select, use `select count(1) from...` in order to find this number (total number of results) before you use the Paginator.

- As for the POST/GET parameters: before you call the paginator loop over the parameters and save them into a string:

`foreach($_GET as $key=> $val){
       $str .= "$key=$val&";}`

Then override the class everytime it creates an `HREF` for example, change:

```
"href=\"{$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]}?page=$i&ipp=$this->items_per_page\">$i</a> ";
```

to:

```
"href=\"{$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]}?" . $str . "page=$i&ipp=$this->items_per_page\">$i</a> ";
```

Comment: the link i provided was an example. the code pasted in my primary post is the actual class ill be using. I figured out the SQL limiter. Here is my solution. http://pastebin.com/qH2La4Mh I am still curious how to fix my url issue with the pagination class listed above in my primary post.

Comment: I think what you are saying is what I need but how would i implement that into the above pagination class (first box of code in my primary post) so that it would work? not the example link you are referring to.

Comment: In the code above there's a comment that says: *You can find examples in the index.php script (with this package)* - it will be a good idea to check these examples for usage.

Comment: i did, and the index.php has no example output of a SQL query.